# Basis over edges of a mesh

Tags: finite-element

In 2D, the *hat functions* are the usual function basis for the finite dimentional space $\{v\in \mathcal{C}:v|_T\in P_1(T)\,\forall T\}$: set of continuously functions that are polynomials less than or equal to one over each element (triangle) $T$ of the mesh.

But, which are the function bases for $\{v:v|_e\in P_k(e)\,\forall e\}$? (space of functions that are polynomials less than or equal to one on edge $e$ of the mesh).

In other words, **how can I define a base of polynomials less than or equal to one over an single edge $e$ of the mesh?**

Comment: Exactly like you would define the hat functions on a 1D mesh: the two linear functions that are equal to $1$ on one of the two vertices and $0$ on the other.